# Return multiple values, including a promise

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, q, es6-promise

```
...
var me = 'you';
return aPromise();
}).then(data => {
  // i want me here
})

function aPromise() {
  return new q.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(iReturnAnObject());
    }, reject);
});
```

I want the `me` variable inside the scope of the `then` method. If I try something like:

```
...
var me = 'you';
return [aPromise(), me];
}).then(data => {
  let promise, me;
  [promise, me] = data;
  console.log(promise); //incomplete object
})
```

The `promise` variable won't contain the entire object aPromise() should return, it's still pending.

Comment: can you clarify what is the purpose of what you are trying to achieve? your code example is incomplete aswell.

Comment: What `aPromise()` function do and what returns?

Comment: actually, `promise` will contain exactly the object `aPromise()` returns, if aPromise returns an unfulfilled promise, then of course `promise` remains unfulfilled until the promise is fulfilled

Comment: Thank you, learned how to promise :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just nest the promise:

```
...
var me = 'you';
return aPromise().then(data => {
  // me is here
})
```

Otherwise, you have to wrap the array of resolved values:

```
  ...
  var me = 'you';
  return Promise.all([aPromise(), me]);
}).then(data => {
  let [promise, me] = data;
  // use me here
  promise.then(...)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
somePromise.then(() => {
    const me = 'you';
    return aPromise().then(aPromiseData => Promise.resolve({aPromiseData, me}))
}).then(data => {
    const {aPromiseData, me} = data;
})
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can inject the var into the success callback.

```js
const other = 'other var';
const promise = new Promise(
        function(resolve, reject) {
            window.setTimeout(
                function() {
                    // We fulfill the promise !
                    resolve('response');
                }, 2000);
        }
    );

// or

promise.then(function(other, response) {
  console.log(other, response);
}.bind(null, other))
```

Can you give more context though?  It might be easier to pass the other variable into resolve().